# It is possible to find current location without GPS in swift?

Tags: swift, gps, currentlocation

I am  trying to find current location using GPS. Now I am getting current location without  GPS. Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    let location = locations.last as CLLocation

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

    //self.mapview.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    var geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in


        if (error != nil) {
            // println("reverse geodcode fail: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            let alert = UIAlertView()
            alert.title = "Location"
            alert.message = "Unable to find Where Am I !!"
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
            alert.show()

            return
        }
}
```